# SQL Server Paging, with dynamic ordering?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-order-by, paging

I found [this nice example](http://www.techipost.com/2010/12/05/how-to-do-paging-in-sql/) of doing paging in SQL Server, however, I need to do some dynamic ordering. That is, the user passes in an integer, which then gets used to do the ordering, like this:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 1 THEN DateDiff(ss, getdate(), received_date)  --oldest
        WHEN @orderBy = 2 THEN DateDiff(ss, received_date, getdate()) --newest
        WHEN @orderBy = 3 THEN message_id --messageid
        WHEN @orderBy = 4 THEN LEFT(person_reference, LEN(person_reference)-1) --personid
    END
```

Is it possible to do paging, with this form of dynamic ordering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do instead is move the ORDER BY code into the ROW_NUMBER window function.

Like this example

```
SELECT * -- your columns
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROWNUM = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY
        CASE WHEN @orderBy = 1 THEN DateDiff(ss, getdate(), received_date)  --oldest
            WHEN @orderBy = 2 THEN DateDiff(ss, received_date, getdate()) --newest
            WHEN @orderBy = 3 THEN message_id --messageid
            WHEN @orderBy = 4 THEN LEFT(person_reference, LEN(person_reference)-1) --personid
        END
    )
    FROM TBL

) R
where ROWNUM between ((@pageNumber-1)*@PageSize +1) and (@pageNumber*@PageSize)
```

The main problem with the complex ORDER BY and the windowing function is that you end up fully materializing the rownum against all rows before returning just one page.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Yeah, your warning about the full table was what I was fearing. it's 'kind of' like selecting the entire table into a temp table, ordering, and then selecting the 'between' bit. So, harsh on the DB, I guess. I believe better paging functuions are coming in the next SQL Server...